# OS X ignoring sshd_config

Tags: osx, encryption, sshd

I'm attempting to remove a number of ciphers from my openSSH installation:

```
ssh -Q cipher

3des-cbc
blowfish-cbc
cast128-cbc
arcfour
arcfour128
arcfour256
aes128-cbc
aes192-cbc
aes256-cbc
rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
aes128-ctr
aes192-ctr
aes256-ctr
aes128-gcm@openssh.com
aes256-gcm@openssh.com
chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
```

I've attempted to remove, for example blowfish-cbc, by editing the configuration file:

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And adding either the line:

```
Ciphers -blowfish-cbc
```

or

```
Ciphers [comma separated list of all other ciphers except for blowfish-cbc]
```

However, upon system reboot or unloading/loading of SSH, blowfish-cbc is still reported in ssh -Q ciphers.

What am I doing wrong?

OS X Version: 10.11.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sshd_config` only affects the *ssh daemon*, while you're testing the *ssh client*, which uses `ssh_config`.